# Dataframe and updating a new column value in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-datareader

I am trying to update a value in a dataframe using a method and a forloop. I pass the dataframe into the method and use a for loop to calculate the value I want to put into the last column.

Here is the method

```
def vwap2(df):
sumTpv = 0.00
sumVolume = 0
dayVwap = 0.00

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    #Get all values from each row
    
    #Find typical price
    tp = (row['HIGH'] + row['LOW'] + row['CLOSE'] + row['OPEN']) / 4
    tpv = tp * row['VOLUME']
    sumTpv= sumTpv + tpv
    sumVolume = sumVolume + row['VOLUME']
    vwap = sumTpv / sumVolume
    #Find VWAP
    #df.assign(VWAP = vwap)
    #row.assign(VWAP = vwap)
    #row["VWAP"] = vwap
    df.set_value(row, 'VWAP', vwap)
    df = df.reindex(row = row)
    df[row] = df[row].astype(float)
    dayVwap = dayVwap + vwap
    
    

print('Day VWAP = ', dayVwap)
print('TPV sum = ', sumTpv)
print('Day Volume = ', sumVolume)
return df
```

And the Dataframe already has the column in it as I add it to it before I pass the df into the method. Like this

```
df["VWAP"] = ""
#do vwap calculation
df = vwap2(df)
```

But the values either are all the same which should not be or are not written. I tried a few things but to no success.

### Updates

Here is the data that I am using, I am pulling it from Google each time:

```
                       CLOSE   HIGH      LOW    OPEN  VOLUME        TP  \
 2018-05-10 22:30:00  97.3600  97.48  97.3000  97.460  371766  97.86375   
 1525991460000000000  97.2900  97.38  97.1800  97.350  116164  97.86375   
 1525991520000000000  97.3100  97.38  97.2700  97.270   68937  97.86375   
 1525991580000000000  97.3799  97.40  97.3101  97.330   46729  97.86375   
 1525991640000000000  97.2200  97.39  97.2200  97.365   64823  97.86375   

                          TPV        SumTPV    SumVol       VWAP  
 2018-05-10 22:30:00  3.722224e+08  1.785290e+09  18291710  97.601027  
 1525991460000000000  3.722224e+08  1.785290e+09  18291710  97.601027  
 1525991520000000000  3.722224e+08  1.785290e+09  18291710  97.601027  
 1525991580000000000  3.722224e+08  1.785290e+09  18291710  97.601027  
 1525991640000000000  3.722224e+08  1.785290e+09  18291710  97.601027
```

As you can see all the calculated stuff is the same.

Here is what I am using right now.

```
def vwap2(df):
sumTpv = 0.00
sumVolume = 0
dayVwap = 0.00

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    #Get all values from each row
    
    #Find typical price
    tp = (row['HIGH'] + row['LOW'] + row['CLOSE'] + row['OPEN']) / 4
    df['TP'] = tp
    
    tpv = tp * row['VOLUME']
    df['TPV'] = tpv
    
    sumTpv= sumTpv + tpv
    df['SumTPV'] = sumTpv
    
    sumVolume = sumVolume + row['VOLUME']
    df['SumVol'] = sumVolume
    
    vwap = sumTpv / sumVolume
    #Find VWAP
    #row.assign(VWAP = vwap)
    #row["VWAP"] = vwap
    #df.set_value(row, 'VWAP', vwap)
    df["VWAP"] = vwap
    dayVwap = dayVwap + vwap
    
    
print('Day VWAP = ', dayVwap)
print('TPV sum = ', sumTpv)
print('Day Volume = ', sumVolume)
return df
```

Comment: It'd be easier to help if you provide example data to work with.  Also, what do you intend to do with `dayVwap`?

Comment: I add the data and I am using dayVwap in a future method to calculate MVWAP which uses the ending total vwap amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you don't need a loop, or even `apply` - you can use direct column assignment and `cumsum()` to get what you're looking for.

Some example data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

N = 20
high = np.random.random(N)
low = np.random.random(N)
close = np.random.random(N)
opening = np.random.random(N)
volume = np.random.random(N)
data = {"HIGH":high, "LOW":low, "CLOSE":close, "OPEN":opening, "VOLUME":volume}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.head()
      CLOSE      HIGH       LOW      OPEN    VOLUME
0  0.848676  0.260967  0.004188  0.139342  0.931406
1  0.771065  0.356639  0.495715  0.652106  0.988217
2  0.288206  0.567776  0.023687  0.809410  0.134134
3  0.832711  0.508586  0.031569  0.120774  0.891948
4  0.857051  0.391618  0.155635  0.069054  0.628036
```

Assign the `tp` and `tpv` columns directly, then apply `cumsum` to get `sumTpv` and `sumVolume`:

```
df["tp"] = (df['HIGH'] + df['LOW'] + df['CLOSE'] + df['OPEN']) / 4
df["tpv"] = df.tp * df['VOLUME']
df["sumTpv"] = df.tpv.cumsum()
df["sumVolume"] = df.VOLUME.cumsum()
df["vwap"] = df.sumTpv.div(df.sumVolume)

df.head()
      CLOSE      HIGH       LOW      OPEN    VOLUME        tp       tpv  \
0  0.848676  0.260967  0.004188  0.139342  0.931406  0.313293  0.291803   
1  0.771065  0.356639  0.495715  0.652106  0.988217  0.568881  0.562178   
2  0.288206  0.567776  0.023687  0.809410  0.134134  0.422270  0.056641   
3  0.832711  0.508586  0.031569  0.120774  0.891948  0.373410  0.333063   
4  0.857051  0.391618  0.155635  0.069054  0.628036  0.368340  0.231331   

     sumTpv  sumVolume      vwap  
0  0.291803   0.931406  0.313293  
1  0.853982   1.919624  0.444869  
2  0.910622   2.053758  0.443393  
3  1.243685   2.945706  0.422203  
4  1.475016   3.573742  0.412737
```

Update (per OP comment):
To get `dayVwap` as the sum of all `vwap`, use `dayVwap = df.vwap.sum()`.

Comment: Thank you I will have to work on this a bit, I need to figure out how cumsum works and how can I keep a sum of the whole volume and I need the volume and tpv to be added up over time . Im new to python so it takes me a bit of time to figure things out.

Comment: You're welcome!  From your code it looks like you want to iteratively add one row's `tpv` value to the sum of all the previous rows of `tpv`, to keep track of a progressive summation (`sumTpv`).  That's what `cumsum` does.

Comment: Your right I figured out how to use it. Your way is really simple and clean. Much nicer I really appreciate it and I learned a lot today

Comment: Great, glad to be of help.